# Strapi.io trigger on Insert to specific Collection

Tags: node.js, strapi

At the moment i try out strapi in order to test whether it is useful for me or not. For testing purposes i want to execute a node.js script when a new entry to a collection is made. This Script should send an E-Mail with a CSV attachment which contains all entered data.

So the following procedure:

1. Application enters new Entry via API Call
2. Strapi notices this and raise a trigger
3. Based on the trigger a custom node.js script executes which send email and attaches

Is this construct possible with strapi or is it to limited for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's absolutely possible by using model's [life cycle hooks](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#available-lifecycle-hooks).
So basically, you just need to override the `afterCreate` hook of the model to listen and trigger mails when a new entry is created like below. For the sake of the example, let's assume you're collection name is `Restaurant`

```js
// Path - /api/restaurant/models/Restaurant.js.
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Triggered before user creation.
   */
  lifecycles: {
    afterCreate(result, data) {
      // add your code here to send a mail here with resto data 
      console.log('inserted data', result);
      console.log('data received', data);
    },
  },
};
```

**References:**

- [Back End Customization](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#models)
- [Life Cycle Hooks](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: @MW00 did this work for you?